# jQuery .html() of all matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.html()` function on class selector (`$('.class').html()`) applies only to the first element that matches it. I'd like to get a value of all elements with class `.class`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are selection all elements with class `.class` but to gather all html content you need to walk trough all of them:

```
var fullHtml;

$('.class').each(function() {
   fullHtml += $(this).html();
});
```

search items by containig text inside of it:

```
$('.class:contains("My Something to search")').each(function() {
   // do somethign with that
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/CC2rL/1/

Comment: It match these elements but not their values.

Comment: Your code matches <a class="class">Something</a>. I just want to match right the "Something" but of all elements with class "class".

Comment: Something like in the second sample?

Answer (score 13):

I prefer a one liner:

```
var fullHtml = $( '<div/>' ).append( $('.class').clone() ).html();
```

Comment: This one would have a side effect, it would try to move the elements of $(".class") to the inside the virtual `div` element, i.e., they would be removed from the actual DOM. You may need to do a `clone()` first, but that would probably too much overhead.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.class').toArray().map((v) => $(v).html())
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality, make sure to provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You could map the `html()` of each element in a filtered jQuery selection to an array and then join the result:

```
           //Make selection
var html = $('.class')
          //Filter the selection, returning only those whose HTML contains string 
          .filter(function(){
              return this.innerHTML.indexOf("String to search for") > -1
          })
          //Map innerHTML to jQuery object
          .map(function(){ return this.innerHTML; })
          //Convert jQuery object to array
          .get()
          //Join strings together on an empty string
          .join("");
```

Documentation:

- [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1):

[Samich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920258/samich) Answer is correct. Maybe having an array of `html`s is better!

```
var fullHtml = [];

$('.class').each(function() {
   fullHtml.push( $(this).html() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you require the whole elements (with the outer HTML as well), there is another question with relevant answers here : [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

A [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741203/1585841) was provided by [@Volomike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105539/volomike) :

```
var myItems = $('.wrapper .items');
var itemsHtml = '';

// We need to clone first, so that we don’t modify the original item
// Thin we wrap the clone, so we can get the element’s outer HTML
myItems.each(function() {
    itemsHtml += $(this).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
});

console.log( 'All items HTML', itemsHtml );
```

An even [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405571/1585841) by [@Eric Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640517/eric-hu). Note that not all browsers support [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) :

```
var myItems = $('.wrapper .items');
var itemsHtml = '';

// vanilla JavaScript to the rescue
myItems.each(function() {
    itemsHtml += this.outerHTML;
});

console.log( 'All items HTML', itemsHtml );
```

I am posting the link to the other answer and what worked for me because when searching I arrived here first.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn your jQuery object into an `Array` you can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over it.

```
const fullHtml = $('.class')
   .toArray()
   .reduce((result, el) => result.concat($(el).html()), '')
```